# ARKit – How to allow detection of an ARAnchor already detected?

Tags: ios, objective-c, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

The following delegate method is fired every time a new anchor is detected:

```
- (void)renderer:(id <SCNSceneRenderer>)renderer didAddNode:(SCNNode *)node forAnchor:(ARAnchor *)anchor
```

It is not fired if the surface has already been detected previously.

My question is: how to allow the firing of this delegate method even if an `ARAnchor` has already been detected?

Answer in Objective-C if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Why and when do you want this method to fire, if not at the time it already does?

Comment: There are delegate methods that fire on add, remove and change